# ImageButton se descuadra al pasarlo al móvil

Tags: android, android-layout, xml

En Android Studio se ve bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el móvil:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="prueba.otrointento.MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffff">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des6"
                android:id="@+id/icon_des6"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des5"
                android:id="@+id/icon_des5"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des3"
                android:id="@+id/icon_des3"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des2"
                android:id="@+id/icon_des2"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des4"
                android:id="@+id/icon_des4"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des1"
                android:id="@+id/icon_des1"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando el mismo tipo de móvil para el emulador?

Comment: No, tengo un OnePlus One (5'5) y no me sale ningún móvil de 5'5, lo mas cerca es 5'2, pero tengo otra activity con iconos bien cuadrados y si sale bien, solamente es solo en ese GridLayout @Error404

Comment: y se vera mal en tablet, y en varios moviles más.
define una vista xml, para cada resolución.
o definelo de forma "porcentual", hay un pequeño truco que permite esto

Comment: Cómo debería hacer eso? El problema es que solo se ven mal los de ese GridLayout, si añado otros iconos fuera del GridLayout se ven perfectamente centrados @Maguz

Comment: estas definiendo el ancho con un wrap_content, esto quiere decir que usas el ancho de la imagen. si la imagen es de 60px de ancho, y la llamas  6 veces, tiene un ancho final de 360px, el problema esta en que hay pantallas cuya resolucion es distinta a esta medida, y es por eso que se ve distinta

Comment: @UserNameYo Entonces me parece que tu problema viene por las distintas resoluciones entre un dispositivo y otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
        <GridLayout
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon_des6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon_des5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon_des3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon_des2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon_des4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon_des1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </GridLayout>
```

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado, dónde estaba el error?

Comment: Como te habían comentado es un problema por resolución de pantallas, en este caso el LinearLayout  y la propiedad android:layout_weight ayuda para distribuirse de forma correcta para las diferentes densidades.

Comment: Por favor da clic o marca como correcta la respuesta si te ayudo.

Comment: Es decir, que debería añadir a esas lineas a las demás activity que tengo para no tener problemas con este tema?

Comment: Depende de la necesidades que tengas amigo, en este caso fue el uso de LinearLayout y un android:layout_weight para la distribución de elementos

Comment: Vale! Gracias de nuevo, marco como resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Debes definir el layout e imagenes para cada vista... yo en tu caso lo definiria en forma porcentual.
Si defines que quieres ver siempre 2 filas con 3 columnas usa este código:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des6"
        android:id="@+id/icon_des6" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.34">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des5"
        android:id="@+id/icon_des5" />
</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des4"
        android:id="@+id/icon_des4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des3"
        android:id="@+id/icon_des3" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.34">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des2"
        android:id="@+id/icon_des2" />
</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des1"
        android:id="@+id/icon_des1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! Pero finalmente quedo resuelto el problema con la solución de @Keops

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente no creo que se descuadren, tu layout es correcto al distribuir los botones,

```
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des6"
            android:id="@+id/icon_des6"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des5"
            android:id="@+id/icon_des5"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des3"
            android:id="@+id/icon_des3"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des2"
            android:id="@+id/icon_des2"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des4"
            android:id="@+id/icon_des4"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_des1"
            android:id="@+id/icon_des1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
    </GridLayout>
```

el problema aquí es que podría ser dificil ver exactamente la distribución en espacios y tamaños en un AVD o dispositivos y que esto se vea exactamente reflejado en otros dispositivos, la razón es principalmente la resolución que manejan los distintos dispositivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, porque especifica cual podría ser la posible causa, que en este caso, probablemente es la resolución de los diferentes dispositivos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! Pero finalmente quedo resuelto el problema con la solución de @Keops

Comment: @UserNameYo en verdad se descuadran, lo que veo en las imagenes es que se ven de diferente tamaño no creo que se descuadren.

Comment: Hola @Elenasys en mi humilde opinión no creo que sean de diferente tamaños las imagenes, lo que pasa es que son de 2 pantallas de diferentes dispositivos (Emulador y dispositivo físico), que por el cambio de densidades, hace que se vea mas grande en uno.  Saludos =)

Comment: Hola si el tamáño puede variar perp no veo que se descuadre como indica el OP.

Comment: Cierto @Elenasys creo que el titulo del problema no fue el adecuado. Saludos.